# Proof that $P_{X,Y}(x,y)=P_X(x)P_Y(y) \iff P_{Y|X}(y|x) = P_Y(y)$

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence

I understand conceptually that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then having information about the state of $X$ will not impact your prediction about the state of $Y$ but I'd like to prove it to myself mathematically... Is there a reasonably easy way to do this or does it require sigma algebras?

Comment: Your title makes no sense, because the left hand side is not a logical expression but the right hand side is.

Comment: fixed the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forward direction:
$$P_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P_X(x)}=\frac{P_{X}(x)P_Y(y)}{P_X(x)}=P_Y(y)$$

The backward direction:
$$P_{Y|X}(y|x)=P_Y(y)\rightarrow \underbrace{P_{Y|X}(y|x)P_X(x)}_{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}=P_Y(y)P_X(x)$$